# How to set route with a slash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is what i have for my routes right now:

[image: route]

What would be the format to add that to the routes like `localhost:3000/appointments/new`?

Comment: Please post the actual code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: can you explain your question? what do you want in output?

Comment: I'd advise you to set those routes for things that alter state to be `POST` or `PUT` at the very least. There's been some unfortunate trouble in the past with browsers pre-fetching links to things and deleting entire databases because of rampant `GET` requests to things like a "Delete" link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use collection routes:

```
resources :appointments do
  collection do
    get :confirm
    get :cancel
    get :history
  end
end
```

It will generate routes like `appointments/confirm`.

Comment: He requires to pass in :id also, so i suggest you should use, member routes

Comment: Your answer does not yield any ids in the routes, e.g: `/appointments/:id/confirm`. But instead `/appointments/confirm`. Which is wrong.

Comment: If he already had routes, that he wants, what reason to write question about it?

Comment: Because he wants to refactor it to use resources instead. Not entirely clear but it's pretty obvious that it is what he wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment above. You should be using `member` routes:

```
resources :appointments, only: [:new] do
  member do
    get :confirm
    get :cancel
    get :history
  end
end
```

Which yields the following routes:

```
        confirm_appointment GET          /appointments/:id/confirm(.:format)        appointments#confirm
         cancel_appointment GET          /appointments/:id/cancel(.:format)         appointments#cancel
        history_appointment GET          /appointments/:id/history(.:format)        appointments#history
            new_appointment GET          /appointments/new(.:format)                appointments#new
```

If you want anything else than `new`. Just pass that in under the `only` array.

Comment: what difference between your routes and OP routes on image?

Comment: @llya None, except of the first line that should get him what he wants anyways. At least with member routes he gets the ID as he wants. Please elaborate on what is wrong with my answer.

Comment: OP asked about routes like `new`, which is `collection` route, not a `member`. It is just a refactoring, not an answer.